# Showing classical spin tensor is time independent for free particle

Tags: general-relativity, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, quantum-spin, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Reading through Weinberg's gravitation book, the following definition is given for the spin tensor (Pauli-Lubanski psuedovector):

$$ S_\alpha = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}
J^{\beta\gamma}U^\delta\tag 1$$
where we have total angular momentum
$$ J^{\alpha\beta} = \int d^3x\  (x^\alpha T^{\beta 0}-x^\beta T^{\alpha 0})\tag 2,$$
four velocity
$$ U^\alpha = \frac{p^\alpha}{\sqrt{-p^\beta p_\beta}} \tag 3,$$
and of course the energy-momentum tensor, here defined as (without interaction of fields)
$$ T^{\alpha\beta}= \sum_n \frac{p_n{}^\alpha p_{n}{}^\beta}{E_n} \delta^3(\mathbf x-\mathbf x_n(t)) \tag 4.$$

**Question:
For a free particle, how might one show** 
$$ \frac{ d S_\alpha}{dt} = 0.\tag 5$$ 
Some things we know:
$$ \partial_\beta T^{\alpha\beta} = 0\to \frac{d}{dt}T^{\alpha 0} = -\partial_i T^{\alpha i}\tag 6$$
$$\frac{dU^\alpha}{dt} = 0\tag 7$$
and $T^{\alpha\beta}$ is symmetric while $J^{\alpha\beta}$ is antisymmetric.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this should be shown through a cancellation from contraction with the levi-civita or explicitly by $\frac{d J^{\beta\gamma}}{dt} = 0$

Comment: Do you know that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm dt}J=0$? Then the result follows from the product rule.